# Computing the structure sheaf $\mathcal{O}_X(U)$ for $U=X\setminus \mathbb{V}(x_0^2+x_1^2+x_2^2)$ and $X=\mathbb{P}^2$.

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry, projective-geometry, affine-varieties, projective-varieties

I was wondering how one computes $\mathcal{O}_X(U)$ for $U=X\setminus \mathbb{V}(x_0^2+x_1^2+x_2^2)$ and $X=\mathbb{P}^2$ by considering the usual cover of $\mathbb{P}^n$ by affine charts $U_i$. Apparently this can be done by first computing $\mathcal{O}_X(U\cap U_i)$ and then considering the restriction of functions to the overlaps $U\cap U_i \cap U_j$.

I understand the definition of $\mathcal{O}_X(U)$ in terms of it being the ring of regular functions $F:U\rightarrow k$ and the idea that one can glue regular functions that agree on intersections of open sets but am not sure how to bring this together to properly calculate this.

Comment: Do you know how to do it in one affine chart? Suppose you considered the chart $x_2 \neq 0$. Then you're interested in $\mathbb{A}^2 \setminus V(x_{0/2}^2 + x_{1/2}^2 + 1)$. What is its ring of regular functions?

Comment: Ok, so I think in that case this is equal to $k[U\cap U_3]=k[x_0,x_1]/\mathbb{I}(\mathbb{A}^2\setminus \mathbb{V}(x_0^2+x_1^2+1))$ and we can introduce a new variable $z$ with $z(x_0^2+x_1^2+1)=1$ so then $k[U\cap U_3]=k[x_0,x_1,z]/ (z(x_0^2+x_1^2+1)-1)$. I am not 100% on this but if it's right am not sure where to take it from here.

Comment: This is then $\{ g/(x_2x_0^2+x_1^2x_2-1)^m :U\cap U_3\rightarrow k \, : \, m\geq 1\}$ I think, so then you can find where these functions agree on overlaps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So first of all, $\mathbb{A}^2 \setminus V(x_{0/2}^2 + x_{1/2}^2 + 1)$ is an open subvariety, not a closed subvariety, of $\mathbb{A}^2$. Therefore, you can't write its ring of regular functions as $k[x_{0/2}, x_{1/2}]/I$ for some ideal $I$. However, the second thing you wrote is correct: you want to consider the *localization* of $k[x_{0/2}, x_{1/2}]$ at the function $x_{0/2}^2 + x_{1/2}^2 + 1$, which is indeed given by $k[x_{0/2}, x_{1/2}, z]/(z(x_{0/2}^2 + x_{1/2}^2 + 1) - 1)$. The localization basically means that you're allowed to invert $x_{0/2}^2 + x_{1/2}^2 + 1$.

Now you take the intersections of the coordinate rings on the three different charts. Why is it enough to simply take the intersection of the coordinate rings? Because the ring of regular functions of $\mathbb{P}^2 \setminus V(x_0^2 + x_1^2 + x_2^2)$ is necessarily a subring of $k(x_0, x_1, x_2)$, which is the field generated over $k$ by all rational functions in $x_0, x_1, x_2$. The intersection of the three coordinate rings is given by rational functions of the form $\frac{g(x_0, x_1, x_2)}{(x_0^2 + x_1^2 + x_2^2)^m}$, where $g(x_0, x_1, x_2)$ is a polynomial of degree $2m$. [Do you see how to prove this last bit?]

Comment: Ok, I think I can follow that, I'm really not sure about the last part though.

Comment: Here is an example: is $x_{0/2} = x_0/x_2$ a regular function on all of $\mathbb{P}^2 \setminus V(x_0^2 + x_1^2 + x_2^2)$? Obviously not, so it does not belong in the intersection. The only thing that can show up in the denominator of a regular function is the thing that we're guaranteed is not every equal to $0$, namely $x_0^2 + x_1^2 + x_2^2$.

Comment: @AshvinSwaminathan this is a very clear and nice answer :)